# How does the court system work in the Judge Dredd universe?

Tags: dredd

The movies are vague about the system a judge can implement in the *Judge Dredd* universe. Apart from the basic, a judge can be the jury, deliver the verdict, and lastly deliver and carry out the sentence.

However, it's not clear if the defendant can appeal his sentence, which would be a bit hard if the judge rules death (assuming family members can not appeal for the defendant), or sue a judge for damage and pain, that sort of thing.

Is the judging system more fleshed out in canon anywhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The Judge System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judge_Dredd#The_Judge_system)

> Street Judges act as police, judge, jury, and executioner. Capital punishment in Mega-City One is rarely used,[48] though deaths while resisting arrest are commonplace.

There apparently is something called the [Special Judicial Squad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Judicial_Squad) which acts as the internal affairs of the judges. This is to monitor and prevent them from becoming corrupt.

Because the Judges are meant to be infallible, their rulings do not require appeals or suffer grievances. In the comics Dredd did the Long Walk after he questioned the Judge system and his actions led to the death of a child.

History of system according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judge_(2000_AD)#Retirement):

> The Judge System was created by Eustace Fargo, special government prosecutor for street crime, between 2027 and 2031, to combat a rising tide of violent crime and to speed up the process of justice. While there was heavy protest in Congress over the idea of abandoning due process, the electorate was in favour and President Gurney (who supported Fargo's plan) was re-elected with a massive majority.
>
> Following the Third World War of 2070 and discovering that President Booth had stolen the election, the Judges invoked the "oldest law of them all" overthrowing the Government of the United States and seizing power, with popular support, and the chief judge became the country's ruler. The Judicial model has subsequently spread throughout the globe becoming the most common form of government on Earth by the 22nd century.

Comment: "discovering that President Booth had stolen the election" - I didn't know Al Gore wrote comics on the side. With Lisp :)